# Create-React-App: sh: 1: react-scripts: Permission denied

Tags: reactjs

I have uploaded npm based project on server, and getting this error.
Already uninstall and then reinstall node.
Why its showing this error??
[image]

Comment: It seems like you're using Create-React-App and uploading the development environment to the server. You should use this only locally. If you want to upload your project to your server you should run `npm run build` first and then upload the static files. For more info, look here: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/

Comment: Ook let me do this.

Comment: Be mindful that `npm run build` produces static files, not a hosting server. You need a separate library to serve these files, you could use something like expressJS. I believe the `build` command also gives some recommendations. This seems to be a tutorial for hosting a nodejs app on your hosting provider: https://www.thecloudkeeper.io/how-to-host-a-nodejs-app-on-cloudways/. Good luck and I hope you figure it out!

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).